# Insertion into a sorted Array, unable to insert 3rd element.

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, object

this is for my data structures and algorithm assignment. I am to create a array of student objects that are sorted by name. My problem is with my insert algorithm. It compares the new students name to names in the array and finds a spot between where it is less than studentArray[i] and greater than sudentArray[i-1]. This code work only if there is at least 3 elements already in the array, to insert the first three I need to figure out a different way, I was able to get the first and second. But, I'm having trouble getting a 3rd one in there, and moving around the elements in the array to keep it sorted. Here is the code for the insert so far.

```
 public boolean insert2(StudentListing newStudent) {
    int low = 0;
    int high = next - 1;
    int i = (low + high) / 2;
    System.out.println("high is " + high + ", i is " + i + ", next is " + next);

    if(next == 0) {
        System.out.println("No students in array");
        studentArray[i] = newStudent;
        next = next + 1;
        numberOfStudents++;
        return true;
    }

    while(numberOfStudents < 3) {
        while(numberOfStudents == 1) {
            if(newStudent.getName().compareTo(studentArray[i].getName()) > 0) {  //If new student is smaller than student in current index i
                studentArray[next] = newStudent;
                next = next + 1;
                numberOfStudents++;
                return true;
            }
            else {  //new student's name is larger than students name in current index i
                studentArray[next] = studentArray[i];
                studentArray[i] = newStudent;
                next = next + 1;
                numberOfStudents++;
                return true;
            }
        while(numberOfStudents == 2) {
                if(newStudent.getName().compareTo(studentArray[i].getName()) < 0)
        }

    }

    while(studentArray[i] != null && !(newStudent.getName().compareTo(studentArray[i].getName()) > 0) && 
        newStudent.getName().compareTo(studentArray[i-1].getName()) < 0 && !(i >= next) && low >= high) {
        System.out.println("high is " + high + ", i is " + i + ", next is " + next);
        if(newStudent.getName().compareTo(studentArray[i].getName()) > 0) 
            {   System.out.println("newStudent is smaller");
                high = i - 1; }
        else {  System.out.println("newStudent is larger");
                low = i + 1; }
        i = (high + low) / 2;
    }
    System.out.println("high is " + high + ", i is " + i + ", next is " + next);
    System.out.println("Finished binary search");
    for(int j = next; j >= i; j--) {
        System.out.println("J is " + j);
        studentArray[j] = studentArray[j-1];
    }
    next = next + 1;
    studentArray[i] = newStudent.deepCopy();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Using array is a hard requirement ? arrayist will be better  in this case

Comment: Unfortunately using an array is required for this assignment.

Comment: I actually solved the issue with getting past 3 elements, it looks really bad though but works. However, when trying to insert a name that should go to the index zero it doesn't and only goes up to index 1.